# Trying to find all macro files in SharePoint 2013

Tags: 2013

I am new to sharepoint.
I am trying to find all macro documents within our farm and output it with the following information

- name
- Full path
- created date
- modified date
- last modified by user
- version number

I am using this code

```
Add-PSSnapin "Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell" 

Get-SPSite -Limit All |
    Get-SPWeb -Limit All |
   Select -ExpandProperty Lists |
    Where { $_.GetType().Name -eq "SPDocumentLibrary" -and
            -not $_.Hidden } |
    Select -ExpandProperty Items |
    Where{$_.File.Name -match ".docm" -or $_.File.Name -match ".xlsm" -or $_.File.Name -match ".pptm" -or $_.File.Name -match ".dotm" -or $_.File.Name -match ".sldm"}|
    Select Name, URL
        @{Name="URL";
          Expression={$_.ParentList.ParentWeb.Url + "/" + $_.Url};



          }

Get-SPWeb | Export-Csv -Path c:\macros.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

The above is working but I am having problems getting the other data that i need, I cant seem to find the properties that i am looking for on an item

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the below code,

```
function Get-DocInventory([string]$webApplicationURL) {
$SPWebApp =  Get-SPWebApplication -Identity $webApplicationURL
#Get all Site collections from the web application 
$SitesCollection = $SPWebApp.Sites
foreach ($site in $SitesCollection){
    foreach ($web in $site.AllWebs) {
        foreach ($list in $web.Lists) {
        if ($list.BaseType -ne “DocumentLibrary”) {
        continue
        }

        foreach ($item in $list.Items) {
        if($item.File.Name -match ".docm" -or $item.File.Name -match ".xlsm" -or $item.File.Name -match ".pptm" -or $item.File.Name -match ".dotm" -or $item.File.Name -match ".sldm"){

        $data = @{
        "Site" = $site.Url
        "Web" = $web.Url
        "list" = $list.Title
        "Item ID" = $item.ID
        "Item URL" = $item.Url
        "Item Title" = $item.Title
        "Item Created" = $item["Created"]
        "Item Modified" = $item["Modified"]
        "Created By" = $item["Author"]
        "Modified By" = $item["Editor"]
        "File Size" = $item.File.Length/1KB
        "File Size (MB)" = $item.File.Length/1MB
        }
        New-Object PSObject -Property $data
        }
        }
        }
        $web.Dispose();
            }
            $site.Dispose()
}
}



Get-DocInventory "Your WEB Application URL" | Export-Csv -NoTypeInformation -Path "c:\Document_Detail_Report.csv"
```

Comment: Did you try this code ?

Comment: Hi Karthik, 

This is just wait i was looking for. Thank you for the help